# Conduct quantile regression with several dependent variables in R

Tags: r, regression, quantile

I'm interested in doing a multivariate regression in R, looking at the effects of a grouping variable (2 levels) on several dependent variables. However, due to my data being non-normal and the 2 groups not having homogenous variances, I'm looking to use a quantile regression instead. I'm using the rq function from the quantreg toolbox to do this.

My code is as follows

```
 # Generate some fake data
   DV = matrix(rnorm(40*5),ncol=5) #construct matrix for dependent variables

   IV =  matrix(rep(1:2,20)) #matrix for grouping factor

   library(quantreg)

   model.q = rq(DV~IV,
             tau = 0.5)
```

I get the following error message when this is run:

```
Error in y - x %*% z$coef : non-conformable arrays
In addition: Warning message:
In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Solution may be nonunique
```

I believe this is due to my having several DVs, as the model works fine when I try using a DV of one column. Is there a specific way I should be formatting my data? Or perhaps there is another function I may be able to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run several regressions, each with the same set of independent variables, but with a different dependent variable, you could write a function and then apply it to all columns of your `DV` matrix and save the models in a list:

```
reg <- function(col_number) {
  model.q <- rq(DV[, col_number] ~ IV, tau = 0.5)
}
model_list <- lapply(1:ncol(DV), reg)
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, it might be that you want a multivariate model accounting for the correlation of the outcome - but then I do not think the `rq` method would be appropriate

Comment: Well at least as the concept of regression has I understand it refers to one dependent variable and one or multiple independent variables (hence "multivariate") - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Thanks for this clarification - I was not aware of that terminology. I edited my post accordingly. However, in the case of `rq`, it is safe to say that it requires one dependent variable

Comment: Is this actually a stats question? Quantile regression for a system of equations?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple responses, what you most likely need is:

```
DV = matrix(rnorm(40*5),ncol=5) #construct matrix for dependent variables
IV =  matrix(rep(1:2,20)) #matrix for grouping factor
library(quantreg)
rqs.fit(x=IV, y=DV, tau=0.5, tol = 0.0001)
```

Unfortunately, there's really not a lot of documentation about how this works.. I can update if i do find it

Comment: Many thanks! I assume the output are the coefficients? Is there anyway to obtain other output measures using rqs.fit (that come automatically when using the rq function)? E.g confidence intervals, residuals etc. And also how to obtain some goodness of fit measures similar to R-squared?